# Backbone rendering list multiple times

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm running into a problem while fetching json from the server and rendering it. The issue is that every json object is got rendered again.

```
var Student = Backbone.Model.extend({
    getConvertedToHash: function () {
        return $.extend({}, this.attributes.student[0], this.attributes.student[1], this.attributes.student[2]);
    }
});
var Group = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Student,
    url: '/students.json'
});
var StudentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'alert alert-info',
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.model.getConvertedToHash().name);
        return this;
    }
});
var GroupView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.container'),
    initialize: function () {
        this.group = new Group();
        this.group.on('add', this.render, this);
        this.group.fetch({
            success: function () {
                console.log('Fetch successful!');
            },
            error: function(model, xhr, options) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        var $ul = $('<ul>').addClass('student-list');
        this.group.each(function (student, index) {
            console.log(student.toJSON());
            var studentView = new StudentView({model: student});
            $ul.append(studentView.render().el);
        });
        this.$el.append($ul);
    }
});
var groupView = new GroupView();
```

Here's my json:

```
[{
    "student": [{
    "name": "john",
    "lastName": "fox",
    "middleName": "yonson"
},{
    "age": 26,
    "gender": "male"
},{
    "passport": "qpuid5423",
    "inn": 123542
}]
},{
    "student": [{
    "name": "peter",
    "lastName": "powell",
    "middleName": "rivierra"
},{
    "age": 26,
    "gender": "male"
},{
    "passport": "qpuid5423",
    "inn": 123542
}]
}]
```

I got 2 objects in my json and all two objects are rendered, so instead of 1 list on a page I got 2 lists. Any thoughts?

**ANSWER!**
'update' event worked for me. From specification "single event triggered after any number of models have been added or removed from a collection." That's exactly what I needed. Maybe that will help somebody who running into the same issue.

Comment: 'update' event worked for me. From specification "single event triggered after any number of models have been added or removed from a collection." That's exactly what I needed. Maybe that will help somebody who running into the same issue.

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer, that makes it more likely to help someone in the future :)

Comment: @Ivan I believe [@ivarni](http://stackoverflow.com/users/957731/ivarni) meant you should post it as answer to your question, not edit your question to include the answer (this way it's easier for future visitors to find). To do so use the *post  answer* form below your question. Once you do add the answer you should also accept it (you do that by ticking of the check mark to the left of the answer), but note that you might need to wait a day before you can do that.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for clarification! At last I did it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'update' event worked for me. From specification "single event triggered after any number of models have been added or removed from a collection." That's exactly what I needed. Maybe that will help somebody who running into the same issue.